# In a linux kernel module, how can I get path of a known inode

Tags: unix, path, kernel-module, inode

In a Unix kernel module (i.e. working in kernel space), I have a inode.
What is the best way (in Linux, Solaris, AIX) can i used to get the absolute path of that file?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you really trying to do?  See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110

Comment: Sorry, i will try to be more accurate: I am monitor events of unix file system from the kernel. For each event, I am getting the inode number and i want to get the absolute path.